# Is it possible to display my theme sidebar in wordpress admin?

Tags: wp-admin, sidebar

I'm trying to create sidebar in my wordpress admin. This is because I'm trying to make my wordpress admin look like my front end.

My front end theme has sidebar in the right side. So i would like to display the same sidebar in my admin area.

I know its possible by editing wordpress core files. But if i update my wordpress core in the future then all my works will be wasted.

So i'm trying to find some alternate ways. Is there any wordpress admin hook available out there to edit admin body, like editing admin header(admin_head) ?

I respect and appreciate everyone's comments/answers. So please help me. 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to try to make the wp-admin area look like the front-end. It's an uphill battle.

Try using my [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin: it allows editing widgets directly from the front-end etc.